# PostgreSQL: OK to allow errors?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, insert

Before I try to insert a row into a PostgreSQL table, should I query whether the insert would violate a constraint?

I do check when the insert would cause unwanted side-effects (e.g., auto-increment) upon an error.

But, if there are no possible side effects, is it OK to just blindly try to insert into a table? Or, is it better practice to prevent errors by anticipating them when possible (as advised in Objective-C)?

Also, when performing the insert inside an SQL function, will other queries (e.g., CTEs) inside the function get rolled back if the insert fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general testing before hand is not a good idea because it requires you to explicitly lock tables to prevent other clients from changing or inserting data between your test and inserts. Explicit locking is bad for concurrency.

Serials getting auto incremented by failed inserts is in general not a problem. Just don't assume the values inserted into the database are consecutive.

A database and obj-c are two completely different things. Let the database check for problems, it is much easier to add the appropriate constraints to your schema then it is to check everything in your client program.

The default is to rollback to the start of the transaction. But you can control it with savepoints and rollback to savepoint. However a CTE is part of the query and queries are always rolled back completely when part of them fails. However you might be able to work around that by splitting the CTE of into a full query that creates a temp table. Then you can use the temp table instead of the cte.